# Any idea about simulating the stroke in iOS Paint app?

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I'm working on an paint app for iOS platform.And I used CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint to make the line more smooth. But I'm stuck in how to simulate the stroke.

Papers 53 is a really cool app. I just wanna simulate the stroke just like what 'Papers 53' does.

Any idea about changing the width of the line dynamically and smoothly during drawing?

Comment: have you seen this project? https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View
maybe could help you.
check this link to: http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/

Comment: This one is pretty useful. Actually my project is based on this repo. But the width of the line is fixed. I've tried change the width by the speed of drawing.(if user is drawing in a high speed, the line will be thick) However, this method cannot provide an perfectly smooth line.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article about this stuff.

http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/

This one is really reliable and I just used its algorithm to simulate smooth stroke by using Quartz2d successfully.